# Hyperlink Symfony in twig

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, twig

I  have a table Movie :

```
 1. id
 2. title
 3. content
 4. links_id (foreign key)
```

And i have a table Links:

```
 1. id   
 2. name  
 3. url
```

And i have page index.html.twig :

```
{% for link in movie.links %}   
   <a href="#{{ link.url }}" >{{ link.url }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to view the url linked table by the movie and that allowed me to redirect to a site based on the URL.
For example i have some data in Table Links :

```
id:1 name : webSite1 url : www.webSite1.com
id:2 name : webSite2 url : www.webSite2.com
```

And i have some data in table Movie :

```
id : 1 
title : title1
content : content1
links_id : 1
```

when I would dispaly a movie with the links 
i try with this :

```
{% for link in movie.links %}   
   <a href="{{ link.url }}" >{{ link.url }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

when I click on **www.webSite1.com** it appears to me that url :

**http://localhost/download/web/app_dev.php/downloads/Movie/show/www.webSite1.com**

I would to redirect in : **www.webSite1.com**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the schemes to your url.

```
<a href="http://{{ link.url }}" >{{ link.url }}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementing to Federkun, other solution is to maintain your original code

```
{% for link in movie.links %}   
  <a href="{{ link.url }}" >{{ link.url }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

But in your database the url should be complete like

```
id:1 name : webSite1 url : http://www.webSite1.com
id:2 name : webSite2 url : http://www.webSite2.com
```

I thought this is better because several websites only recognize "https" protocol

Answer (score -1):

If you want to render an absolute url in twig you want to be using the `url()` function. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#url

The `path()` function generates a relative url.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path